# Is there a word for a group of shapes?

Tags: collective-nouns

Is there a word for a collection of shapes?

For example: one triangle, two squares and three circles.

Comment: What is the common characteristic of these shapes? What ties them together as a group? For example, I could have suggested *polygon*, except that you mentioned the circle, which has no sides or angles. If you want the word for "all possible shapes", with no further qualification, then the word is simply *shape*.

Comment: _Closed plane figures_ if they are closed like a triangle or square; just _plane figures_ if they aren't all closed.

Comment: I don't think he's looking for a word for the concept of shapes. He wants a word for a collection of specific shapes. But I'm not aware of such a word. Can you show the context where you would use the word?

Comment: @DanBron: But isn't a circle [a polygon with infinite sides](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524594/prove-using-integration-that-polygon-%E2%86%92-circle-space-textas-space-number-spac)? Your suggestion holds good, I'd say.

Comment: @TusharRaj You have to be very careful with limits. Saying "X is Y *in the limit*" is very different from saying "X is Y" without the qualification. If you conflate the two you quickly start running into mathematical absurdities and contradictions. It's a very common sort of category error kids will make when they first start learning algebra and later calculus, and leads to no end of amusing stories and situations. But, if you still like *polygon*, [Josh Thomas has offered it in his answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/255011/55623), so you could upvote him.

Comment: The theory of sets uses the term set for elements that form a group.

Answer (score 1):

That would be ***[geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_shape)***.

> two-dimensional geometric shapes are called polygons and include triangles, squares, and pentagons. Others may be bounded by curves such as the circle or the ellipse.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_shape

Comment: If you're going to quote, don't _introduce_ errors. 'Many two-dimensional geometric shapes can be defined by a set of points or vertices and [straight] lines connecting the points in a closed chain, as well as the resulting interior points. Such shapes are called polygons and include triangles, squares, and pentagons'

Answer (score 1):

["Geometric shapes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_shape) is a good answer. But perhaps not *exactly* what you're looking for.

Your examples are all basic shapes, like "circle, triangle, and square." These are all *two-dimensional* figures. Since "geometric shapes" can be of any dimension, the best answer for you may be: **"two-dimensional geometric shapes."**

Informally, you could just say "two-dimensional shapes" or even "two-dimensional figures."

Answer (score 0):

If there are no circles in the group, and if you don't want to use the word "shapes" (which by definition is a group of shapes), perhaps you could use polygons.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polygon

Comment: A "polygon" has straight sides.  Yes, you can approximate a circle with an infinitely-sided polygon, but it's probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: "If there are no circles in the group"

Answer (score 0):

Probably the term you are looking for is ***[geometrics](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/geometrics)***:

> - Straight lines and simple geometric shapes, e.g., circles and squares, used together to form a design or pattern. (ODO)
> - A pattern or design characterized by the use of geometric figures: Bright geometrics enhance the cloth's appearance. (AHD)

Answer (score 0):

> **Polyform:** a plane figure constructed by joining together identical basic polygon
>
> > Eg: ***Polyomino*:** a plane geometric figure formed by joining one or more equal squares edge to edge
> >
> > > Eg: ***Domino*:** a polyomino of order 2

Briefly, polyform is the enumeration of all possible shapes. The game Tetris was designed with a set of [tetrominos](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Tetromino) forming a rectangle.

Here's a picture of a circle formed by polyominoes:

[image: Polyominium]

[[RecMath]](http://recmath.org)

Answer (score 0):

Is [padstack](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Johnson/ECE189/Mentor2007/LibMngr/Glossary/Glossary.html) the term you're looking for?

**Padstack**

*A "padstack" is a collection of geometric shapes appearing on each of mask layers surrounding a through-hole in a printed circuit board. There are also padstack-related geometries associated with surface-mounted devices. The "Padstack Library" is one of the libraries present in the central library. Each padstack in this library is a representation of a pad or through-hole to be used in a design. Padstacks are referenced in making Cells; they are very detailed. They contain exact dimensions that must precisely correspond to the description of the manufacturer's package. Our central library has most of the padstacks that we will need already defined, so once you import all of the padstacks to your project's central library, there should be no need to edit them or to create more. If you have the need to create more, access the padstack tutorial for further information.*